# Select only columns of interest dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a dynamic pandas dataframe from some values. The dataframe dynamically obtains the name of the columns. Each column name has a numeric sequence that concatenates the name:

> Name_Column_1, Name_Column_2, etc.

In context, each column name is a category of the data. The data can repeat its category, that's why I concatenated a number in its name

> Name_1, Email_1, Phono_1, Name_2, Email_2, Phono_2, etc

What I want is to keep only the columns that interest me regardless of their number.
To explain myself, in SQL language it would be something like:

> SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column_name LIKE 'Email%'

I've been looking for a way to do it, but I can't find an answer.

Do you recommend any features please?

From already thank you very much.

Regards

Comment: `df.filter(like='Email')` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can try `DataFrame.filter`

```py
out = df.filter(like='Email')
```

If you are interested in the number

```py
out = df.filter(regex='Email_[1-5]')
```